# Converting Spring MVC 4 to Spring MVC 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My team member trying to convert Spring MVC 4 to Spring MVC 5. Now what is happening is it is throwing 404 error with exception logging as "*No mapping found for GET request*". I saw on a few of the forums to use **@EnableWebMvc** in the Java Configuration class and declare a **<mvc:annotation-driven />** member in XML.
The 404 is not fixed yet we will try those options.

Appreciate it if you can let me know if there is anything more to be changed. It is a Spring MVC application with XML configuration. I was wondering do we have any step-by-step best approach which can be followed for migrating Spring MVC 4 to Spring MVC 5. I was more curious to validate all checkpoints.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any special reason to keep XML configuration? You should be able to do whatever um have in XML with JavaConfig counterparts. Still, check if this helps —> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-50

Comment: did you make sure the context configuration did not get lost and you are calling the right url?

Comment: @wemu - Could you please elaborate, I didn't understand what makes you think the context configuration is lost? There are no changes made, it was an existing application

Comment: just a wild guess. 404 could mean the restcontrollers are not picked up or you are calling a url that does not exist. often in that case the context is not what one thinks it is. I would start the boot app in debug logging mode, as all the context information and controllers that are picked up are logged.